# How to Remove duplicates from a Lookup File using Python?

Tags: python, duplicates

I've seen multiple responses around this type of question, but i don't believe I've seen any for the type of list I am concerned with.  Hopefully I am not duplicating anything here.  Your help is much appreciated!

I have a comma separated file that I use for data enrichment.  It starts with the headers -  `TPCode,corporation_name` - then the list of values follows.  There are around 35k rows (if that matters).

I notice when the data from that lookup file (CSV) is displayed there are multiple entries for the same customer.  Rather than going in and manually removing them, I would like to run a Python script to remove the duplicates

In the format of:

- *value,value*
- *value,value*
- *value,value*

  etc., what is the optimal way to remove the duplicates using Python?  As a side note, each TPCode should be different, but a corp name can have multiple TPCodes.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way would be to make each row a tuple with individual values and then add them to a set. This would result in only the unique values being added to the set. Once you have that you can write the tuples to a new csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your question if each line should be unique. If so you could do:

```
for l in sorted(set(line for line in open('ors_1202.log'))):
    print(l.rstrip())
```

otherwise we need more info.

Comment: Hi Jonas - Thanks for your input.  Yes, each line should be unique, however one exception would be that there could be the same corporation_name with different TPCodes.  Does that help?

Comment: That sounds to me like you're implying that they are all unique. The same customer will appear only once per corporation_name and TPCode.

Comment: This is true @Jonas.  Although there may be multiple customer names, the TPCodes are unique, making each TPCode,corporation_name pair unique.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the csv rows are tuple and tuples are immutable objects you can loop over your rwos and use a `set` container to hold the rows :

```
import csv
seen=set()
with open('in_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile,pen('out_file.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',')
     for row in spamreader:
           seen.add(row)
           if row not in seen :
               pamwriter.writerow(row)
```

Note that member ship checking in `set` has O(1) complexity.

Comment: Thanks Kasra.  Rather than pen('out_file.csv', 'wb') do you mean open('out_file.csv', 'wb')?